Property 'sendFile' does not exist on type 'Response' in Express TypeScript application
I'm working on an Express application with TypeScript, and I'm encountering the following error when trying to use the sendFile method in my route handler:

Property 'sendFile' does not exist on type 'Response'.ts(2339)

Here's the relevant code snippet:
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

// Serve static files from React build
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));

// Handle routes by sending to build index
app.get("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
});


Steps I’ve Taken
I have ensured that I have the correct types installed. My package.json includes:

"devDependencies": {   "@types/express": "^4.17.21",   ... }

I have reinstalled all dependencies using the following commands:
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

I also tried creating a custom type declaration for the sendFile method, but that didn’t resolve the issue. Here’s the declaration I attempted:
// Augmenting the express module to include the sendFile method
declare module 'express' {
  interface Response {
    sendFile: (path: string, options?: any) => void;
  }
}

My tsconfig.json looks like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Additional Information
Node.js version: v20.16.0
TypeScript version: ^5.6.2
Express version: ^4.17.21
Despite trying various solutions, I’m still unable to resolve this issue. Any help or guidance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank You!

Are you using some kind of IDE which has a "go to definition ..." or similar? Where does this take you when you do this on Response in your importstatement?

Are you sure that the Request object in the route is the Request interface define in Express? could it be that typescript compiler is referring to a different Request interface?

and as you as you are importing the whole express namespace anyways, you could try to use (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {...} instead, just to be sure, you are using the correct type. If that still doesn't work, there is some major issue with your installed packages. Do you have a package-lock.json? You could try removing that as well before reinstalling
